# how to pass locals into a partial rendered with to_partial_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

I've been looking [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) and was wondering whether you can add locals to the shorthand notation for rendering collections of partials?
neither:

```
<% for contact in @contacts %>
  <%= render contact, locals: {my_bool: true, project: @project} %>
<% end %>
```

nor:

```
<%= render @contacts, locals: {my_bool: true, project: @project} %>
```

appear to work, is there a way to allow this to work or will these partials not accept arguments like this for additional locals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct syntax is,

```
 <%= render @contacts, my_bool: true, project: @project %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it right now, but I think you need to specify that you are rendering a partial for locals to be accepted:

```
<%= render partial: 'contact', locals: {my_bool: true, project: @project} %>
```

By the way, `@project` being an instance variable will be accessible from the partial, so it's kind of redundant to use it here. `my_bool` will be accessible as a regular variable, not an instance one, keep that in mind.

Comment: yep, you're right, I just like being explicit as I find it makes maintaining the code easier (although now that you say that it is at the cost of one variable creation and I am against doing things unneccessarily).